# sddm.conf and HaltCommand

Tags: shutdown, sddm

I'm using Kubuntu 19.10. My goal is to power off the system only if `rsnapshot` is not running.

So I need to setup up my own `poweroff` command and the first idea was to use `sddm.conf` file, `HaltCommand=mypoweroff`.

But whatever the command Halt I set, when a user asks for a poweroff, the system power off immediately.

Do you know if I can use that `HaltCommand` or not and how to use it?